# Convert curl request to angular http, using --user

Tags: angular, curl

I have this curl request that works good:

```
curl  --user admin:adminpwd http:...v1?qry=name%3D%27Max%27
```

I get results as expected.

Now I'm trying to call the same request from my angular app:

```
 search() {
    return this.http
      .get<Student>(
        'http:...v1',  -- my url
        {
          headers: 
         {   
            Authorization: 'Basic '+ btoa("admin:adminpwd")
         },
         params: 
        {
          qry: 'name%3D%27Max%27',
        }
    }
  );
```

}

Bot I get a CORS error:

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http...v1?qry=name%253D%2527Max%2527' from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been 
blocked by CORS policy: Request header field authorization is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in 
preflight response.
```

Can you please advise what is the currect syntax?

Thanks!

Comment: you need to allow CORS on your server, curl/postman doesn't implement CORS, angular uses browser which implemented CORS

Comment: Which web server are you using? You need to 'authorization' header to be accepted. You do this by adding it to 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers'. Solution varies by the server

Comment: Is this Access-Control-Allow a change in angular request ot in the server side? If in ckient side, can you advise regarding the exacr syntax? Thanks!